# how to find string with number selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to find the class along with number digits, for instance, the class maybe like this: `.test_ico1, .test_ico2, .test_ico3, .test_ico4.`

**Jquery**

```
$('.test_ico' + '/[0-9]/').each(function(){
    var a = window.getComputedStyle(this,':after').content;
$(this).parent().hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-content', a);
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem in this jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^`(`starts with`) symbol.

Also it's called [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[class^="test_ico"]').each(function(){
```

**Short example:**

```js
 $('[class^="myClass"]').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.active{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myClass1">1</li>
  <li class="myClass2">2</li>
  <li class="Class3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `[attribute*=value]`

```
$('[class*="test_ico"]').each(function(){
    var a = window.getComputedStyle(this,':after').content;
$(this).parent().hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-content', a);
    });
});
```

**Note**: Prefer this over @Alexandru's answer only if your element has multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [starts with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), no need for a each function, you need the hover event over the test_ico not the parent

```
$('[class^="test_ico"]').hover(function() {
        var a = window.getComputedStyle(this,':after').content;
        $(this).parent().attr('data-content', a);
    });
```